# Haskell custom data type and reprsentation

Tags: haskell

Say there is a stadium and the row number is something like A1-10, then B1-10 and so on until ZZ

How do I make a custom data type and use it to represent the seat in Haskell?

Comment: Use record datatype to store the first and second part separately.

Comment: "Until ZZ" meaning that after `Z` you get to `AA`, then `AB`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz yes thats right

Comment: mmm `(Maybe Char, Char, Int)` sounds too complicated for my taste... dunno. A funny problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the row number varies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of your enumeration as being composed of three parts

- a first letter,
- an (optional) second letter, and
- a number between 1 and 10

The first and second part both rely upon the notion of "letter", so let's define that

```
data Letter
  = La | Lb
  | Lc | Ld
  | Le | Lf
  | Lg | Lh
  | Li | Lj
  | Lk | Ll
  | Lm | Ln
  | Lo | Lp
  | Lq | Lr
  | Ls | Lt
  | Lu | Lv
  | Lw | Lx
  | Ly | Lz
  deriving ( Eq, Ord, Show )
```

This type is explicitly enumerated instead of merely using `Char` so that we don't have to worry about the differences between lower and upper case or the problems of `Char` containing extra things like `'-'` and `'^'`. Since I enumerated the elements in alphabetical order, the autoderived instances like `Ord` behave properly.

We probably do want to take advantage of the fact that `Letter` is a subset of `Char` so let's write the projections, too.

-- This one always works since every letter is a character.

```
letterToChar :: Letter -> Char
letterToChar l = case l of
  La -> 'a'
  Lb -> 'b'
  Lc -> 'c'
  Ld -> 'd'
  Le -> 'e'
  Lf -> 'f'
  Lg -> 'g'
  Lh -> 'h'
  Li -> 'i'
  Lj -> 'j'
  Lk -> 'k'
  Ll -> 'l'
  Lm -> 'm'
  Ln -> 'n'
  Lo -> 'o'
  Lp -> 'p'
  Lq -> 'q'
  Lr -> 'r'
  Ls -> 's'
  Lt -> 't'
  Lu -> 'u'
  Lv -> 'v'
  Lw -> 'w'
  Lx -> 'x'
  Ly -> 'y'
  Lz -> 'z'


-- This one might fail since some characters aren't letters. We also do
-- automatic case compensation.
charToLetter :: Char -> Maybe Letter
charToLetter c = case Char.toLower of
  'a' -> Just La
  'b' -> Just Lb
  'c' -> Just Lc
  'd' -> Just Ld
  'e' -> Just Le
  'f' -> Just Lf
  'g' -> Just Lg
  'h' -> Just Lh
  'i' -> Just Li
  'j' -> Just Lj
  'k' -> Just Lk
  'l' -> Just Ll
  'm' -> Just Lm
  'n' -> Just Ln
  'o' -> Just Lo
  'p' -> Just Lp
  'q' -> Just Lq
  'r' -> Just Lr
  's' -> Just Ls
  't' -> Just Lt
  'u' -> Just Lu
  'v' -> Just Lv
  'w' -> Just Lw
  'x' -> Just Lx
  'y' -> Just Ly
  'z' -> Just Lz
  _   -> Nothing -- default case, no match
```

Now we play the same game with "digits from 1 to 10"

```
data Digit
  = D1 | D2
  | D3 | D4
  | ...
  deriving ( Eq, Ord, Show )

digitToInt :: Digit -> Int
digitToInt = ...

intToDigit :: Int -> Maybe Digit
intToDigit = ...
```

We might even write other ways of retracting an `Int` to a `Digit`. For instance, we could (1) take the absolute value of the integer and then (2) take its `div` and `mod` against 10 seats. This will result in a `Digit` assignment and a row number.

```
intToDigitWrap :: Int -> (Int, Digit)
intToDigitWrap n = (row, dig) where
  (row, dig0) = n `divMod` 10
  -- we use an incomplete pattern match because we have an invariant
  -- now that (dig0 + 1) is in [1, 10] so intToDigit always succeeds
  Just dig    = intToDigit (dig0 + 1)
```

And the final type is easy!

```
data Seat = Seat { letter1 :: Letter
                 , letter2 :: Maybe Letter
                 , digit   :: Digit
                 } deriving ( Eq, Ord, Show )
```

The `Ord` type is again completely automatically correct as `Nothing` is less than `Show x` for any `x` and record ordering is lexicographic. We can also write a show instance that's a bit friendlier very simply

```
prettySeat :: Seat -> String
prettySeat s = 
  let l1 = [Char.toUpper $ letterToChar $ letter1 s]
      l2 = case letter2 s of
             Nothing -> ""
             Just c  -> [Char.toUpper $ letterToChar c]
      dig = show (digitToInt (digit s))
  in l1 ++ l2 ++ "-" ++ dig
```

In all likelihood the ability to inject the `Letter` and `Digit` types into their superset types `Char` and `Int` respectively will almost certainly come in handy when writing code later.

Comment: I would derive `letterToChar` and `charToLetter` from `fromEnum` and `toEnum`, plus some bounds checking. (Of course, after `deriving (...,Enum)`).

Comment: I probably would too in earnest—less chance for typo-based errors. For some reason I felt writing it out in full would be illustrative, though.